# How to verify mongoDB options set on connection level

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Is there a way to verify options / settings that are set on the connection level?

For example we set the following options:

```
repository.options.w = 'majority';
repository.options.j = true;
repository.options.readConcern = { level: 'linearizable' };
repository.options.retryWrites = true;
repository.options.wtimeout = 5000;
```

I tried to verify them on the driver level within our application, once the connection is established but that seems to accept values that are not valid. E.g. I can set the value for the readConcern to { level: 'notValid' } and get that reflected within the server option after establishing the connection.

I was hoping to find a way to verify the options from within mongodb itself.